# XPATH - Grab only certain part of string from inside a div tag

Tags: xpath

I was wondering if anyone out there could help me, I am trying to grab only the date information from the following div:

```
<div class="example-div">TT-120171 | 2013-10-29</div>
```

I can grab the whole contents but don't need them and need it to work programmatically so I only get the date:

2013-10-29

NOT the whole thing:

TT-120171 | 2013-10-29

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If `expression` is what you use to extract the whole string I would suggest that you use

```
normalize-space(substring-after(expression, '|'))
```

as your final XPath expression. Note that this solution strongly depends on the *exact* formatting of your input file so it is likely to break. But this is something you always have to be aware of when you do 'scraping' of unformatted input.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am a bit of novice though! How do I incorporate the code above into my original code which is: .//div[@class='example-div'] Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: In this case `expression` would be `.//div[@class='example-div']`. :-)

Comment: Ah! So I need to replace the word 'expression' with MY expression? haha, I see now. I'll give it a go. Thanks very much.

Comment: Does it work? If so, could you pick your answer, please? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I cannot get it working and now cannot get the information from the actual div in its entirety. Will take another look later at this!